# How to enter 'blank' values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, vba

I am using VBA to write some values to MySQL table as rows. However, for certain columns, I want to leave them blank so that the default value of NULL can be assumed by the database.

I need to specify all column values in my SQL query. Can I write something like this (two consecutive commas represent a blank column):

```
SQLStr = "insert into table tablename values (12,13,19,,,,,1,,2,,5)"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `NULL`:

```
insert into table tablename
    values (12, 13, 19, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, NULL, 2, NULL, 5);
```

You can also use `''` if the column is a string and by "blank" you mean "empty string".

I should add . . . you should always list the columns you are inserting, so it is better to write this as:

```
insert into table tablename(col1, col2, col3, col8, col10, col12)
    values (12, 13, 19, 1, 2, 5);
```

(You don't specify what the column names are.)

By default, SQL will put `NULL` values in for the missing columns -- this can be prevents (using `NOT NULL`) or another value used (using `DEFAULT`).